Can't change material for animation using Mix Shader

A title says, i've seen tutorials in order to change material for animation (i want the clothes to dissapear and the re-appear) but no matter what i do the i can't change between my material and a transparent bsdf. I also should note that i'm using vertex groups for the clothes, since i want to have one armature moving everything.
The photo shows the mix shader just changing the color of the original material and nothing else, no matter the factor it won't change to transparent or have the original color again.
Thanks in advance!

You're using a mix color node, that is warning you that's sometihing is wrong, while you should use a mix shader node.

thanks, it feels like a stupid question, but you really helped me

You are welcome, we all passed thorough this.
